# Eclipse IDE: How to add this configuration during running?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, pythonpath

For running of one of my C++ programs, using terminal(Ubuntu) I use

Note: I'm trying to Embed Python in C++. Hence, PYTHONPATH in C++.
Refer to Python/C API for more details.

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. ./prog_name
```

Sorry, I didn't know how to ask this question on Google. I want to do the same running with Eclipse. I don't know where to specify PYTHONPATH=. during running from Eclipse. How to produce the equivalent of this? I tried putting in argument list, but obviously it didn't work. Thanks!

PS. Don't downvote just because you don't understand that python scripts can be called through C++ .. Lol

Comment: why would you want to add pythonpath for running C++ programs?

Comment: @user2963623 I'm trying to embed Python in C++, hence running a python script from a C++ program.

Comment: Do you have pydev installed?

Comment: @user2963623 Why would I need pydev, I'm using the Python/C API...<Python.h>. PS. I'm not trying to run python scripts from Eclipse.

Comment: Well I don't know how to add to pythonpath in this case, but usually in Eclipse there's an option to edit pythonpath in windows->preferences->pydev->...

Comment: @user2963623 thats for pydev (Python through Eclipse) which wont work here, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi to all those facing the same problem, i found the solution!
setenv() is a function defined in  which sets the environment variable. Just have to  run it!

```
setenv("PYTHONPATH",".",1);
```

for more info on setenv:

```
$ man setenv
```

All the best :)